# Constructor in Interface and abstract?

Tags: java, android, interface, abstract-class

So lets say I have this interface:

```
public interface IBox
{
     public void onEvent(int eventType, View control, Object data);
}
```

And I have a class access it:

```
  public class Rectangle 
    {
    private IBox onEvent;


public Rectangle(Context context, View rowRoot) {
        super(context);
        onEvent = (Rectangle) context;
    }
      @Override

    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonClick:
                // send data : data1 and data2;
                onEvent.onEvent(data1,null, data2);
            break;
    }
```

and I have a class implement `IBox`:

```
 public abstract class BaseActivity implements IBox
    {
    @Override
        public void onEvent(int data1, View data, Object data2)
       {
      //do something here
       }
    }
```

and I have class extends `BaseActivity` class:

```
public class HomeBaseActivity extends BaseActivity
{
   // transit Activity here, or send intent....
}
```

Final I have class main extends `HomeBaseActivity`:

```
public class HomeActivity extends HomeBaseActivity 
     {

            @Override
            public void onEvent(int data1, View data, Object data2)
           {
          switch (data1) {
           //reciver data1 from class Rectangle
           }
     }
```

> My question:
>
> 1, why data1 can reciver in class HomeActivity?
>
> 2, any body can explain , help me ?
>
> // a have litter english , so thanks

Comment: The code you posted will not work because variable `onEvent` in class `Rectangle` is never initialised. It *could* work is somwhere in your real code assignes an object of class `HomeActivity` to variable `onEvent` in class `Rectangle`.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear; *why data1 can receiver* ... what do you mean with that?

Comment: @ Timothy Truckle  : sorry , i initialised in contructor , but don't necessary , so i don't post , i edited

Comment: @GhostCat : it mean : in class HomeActivity, reciver data1 success, how send? i don't understand.

Comment: @manhthang You can't do this: `onEvent = (Rectangle) context;`. `Rectangle` has nothing related to `IBox` or `Context`.

Comment: @manhthang Check my answer. Feel free to ask if you have anything to concern.

Answer (score 0):

I am understanding that you are wondering why from `onClick()` in `Rectangle`, we can pass values to `onEvent()` in `HomeActivity` and assumpting that your activity is extending `Context` (every activity have to extend `Context`).

Let's see here. `HomeActivity` is extending `HomeBaseActivity` which is implementing `IBox`. Basically, an object that `new HomeActivity()` can be cast to `IBox`. *[1]*

Besides, as my assumption above, your activity is extending `Context`. *[2]*

*[1][2]* => an instance of `HomeActivity` can be cast to `IBox` and `Context`.

Let's pass an object of `HomeActivity` to your `Rectangle` (being cast to `Context`) and assign to `onEvent` property (now being cast to `IBox`).

Now in your `onClick()`, `onEvent.onEvent(data1,null, data2);` just simply calls the `onEvent()` method you implemented in `HomeActivity`. That's why you can pass `data1` to `HomeActivity`.

Learn more about interface and inheritance in Java [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html).

*P/s: If you got troubles in reading English, just ask, I can explain to you in private using your native language for this time. Try to improve your English, at least for everybody to understand you. Because here we discuss in English.*